# Reprojection error formula

Tags: projective-geometry, computer-vision

In a paper,the pinhole camera model is defined as follows:

$$
w\small
\left(\begin{array}{c}
 u\\
 v \\
1
\end{array}\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 f_{u} & 0 & u_{c}\\
 0       & f_{v} & v_{c}\\
 0       &         0 &      1
\end{array}
\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{R}_{c}^{T} &-\mathbf{R}_{c}^{T}\mathbf{t}_{c}
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{ p}\\
1
\end{array}\right)= \mathbf{K} \mathbf{P}_{c}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{ p}\\
1
\end{array}\right).
$$
Where $f_{u}$ and $f_{v}$ are the focal lengths in $u$ and $v$ directions,
the principal point offset $(u_{c}, v_{c})$.
$t_{c}$ the position of the camera center in a world frame and $R_{c}$ the
rotation from the camera back to the world frame.
$p$ is a 
D point in the world frame.
If $u_{i}$ and $v_{i}$ denote the measurements of point $p_{i}$, the reprojection error is as follows:
$$
\epsilon_{i}= \small
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 u_{i}\\
 v_{i}
\end{array}\right)-\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0& 0 &1\end{array}\right) & \mathbf{K} \mathbf{P}_{c} & \left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{p}_{i}\\
1\end{array}\right) 
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 &0 \\
0 &1 &0
\end{array}\right) \mathbf{K} \mathbf{P}_{c}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{ p_{i}}\\
1
\end{array}\right)
$$

I don't understand how the expression of the reprojection error is derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square is measuring the third coordinate entry, which is the homogenization coordinate $w$. By multiplying with it's inverse, i.e. dividing by $w$, you are dehomogenizing, ensuring a $1$ in the third coordinate and also dropping that coordinate thanks to the $2\times3$ matrix. The result will be a 2d Euclidean distance vector between projected and actual point in the plane.